# Why does Maxima display an incorrect function graph?

Tags: maxima

There is a function

```
(x-1)/log(x)
```

It is clear that the graph should be displayed starting with x>0. However, Maxima also displays on x<0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you must be calling `draw2d` or `wxdraw2d`. (It's probably always a good idea to post the exact code you are working with.) `draw2d` has an option named `draw_realpart` to control whether the real part of a complex result is plotted, which appears to be `true` by default.

Try `draw2d(draw_realpart = false, explicit(...))` in order to cause only real values to be plotted.

`plot2d` likewise has an option `plot_realpart`, which see.